# How precise is WinAPI's Sleep()?

Tags: winapi, sleep

And I don't mean precision to one millisecond, I'm asking about a situation when I want a delay of an hour using `Sleep(60 * 60 * 1000)`. Will it be an hour and not like 55 or 70 minutes? Is thread guaranteed to wake up and not sleep forever?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that threads might not be the correct tool to solve your current task?

Comment: @asawyer What can I use instead in simple C environment?

Comment: @mrpyo: What are you trying to ultimately trying to accomplish? Your needs might be better met with a scheduled task, timer or similar. Your question reminded me of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx) blog post (not that I'm shaking my head in disbelief, but I'm curious as to why you want to `Sleep` for an hour).

Comment: `Sleep` is rarely the right solution to a problem.

Comment: @user786653 Oops, you were right... I guess what I wanted is `CreateTimerQueueTimer()` function. Well, I was misled by some posts over the internet proposing just using `Sleep()` in similar situations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over an hour, the accuracy of a Sleep() call is not that bad, (it's fairly easy to test as well).  A Sleep() call will return sufficiently close to the hour that it is not possible to determine any error with a manual stopwatch, (tried it on XP - no reason for it to be any different now, AFAIK).

Errors wrt. wall-time will, of course accumulate if consecutive calls to Sleep(3600*1000) are made, especially if the operations performed at theend of each interval are themselves lengthy and/or the box is seriously overloaded, (ie. many more ready threads than cores).

Why would the thread sleep forever if you ask it to sleep for an hour?  If you call Sleep(3600*1000), it will become ready after that time.  If it does not, the OS is stuft anyway and you're on your way to a reboot.

The reason why such a Sleep() call might be prefered over some timer is that it's a one-liner and will work anywhere on the caller stack - no need for a message-handler and/or state-machine to handle the timer callback.

Comment: I figure what I wanted is a timer not `Sleep()`. But that leaves a question - is using `Sleep()` inherently wrong? Should I always use `CreateTimerQueueTimer()` (or `SetTimer()` when I have message pump)?

Comment: @mrpyo - if you have a message-driven GUI thread, or similar, then yes, use a timer class that sends WM_TIMER messages.  You must not wait/sleep in a GUI event-handler.  Sleep() is indeed inherently wrong in a GUI-style thread that must process input in a timely manner.

Comment: +1 for the `one-liner`. Otherwise a waitable timer may make the `wakeup` more predictable (to less than a milisecond if done correctly). However, still it depends whether the scheduler allows the task to get scheduled at that time or whether other tasks are prohibiting it.

Comment: @Arno +1, yes.  That's why I was careful to say that the thread would become ready - not necessarily running:)  Most supermarket value timers have no better precision/accuracy than Sleep() since they use the same OS mechanism underneath.  There are 'better' timers but, of course more hassle, (eg. multimedia timers), but yes, it's still possible that driver interrupts and/or higher-priority threads will stuff up your timeout.